# How do I extend a static class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

What's wrong with my code? It says

> (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mp2\oop.php on line 7)

I don't know why `public` is unexpected. I'm trying to learn by myself.

```
<?php
    class MyClass{
    public static function funct(){
        echo "JHAN VINCENT VILLASIN";
        }
    }

    public MyNewClass extends MyClass{ 
    }
    MyClass::funct();
?>
```

Comment: by the way this is my codes : 

<?php
class MyClass{
public static function funct(){
echo "JHAN VINCENT VILLASIN";
}
}
public MyNewClass extends MyClass{}
 MyClass::funct();
?>

Comment: How is it unclear what the question is?

Comment: Ex C# developer, are you? ;) You got to tell the class declaration that it is a class declaration, so `public MyNewClass` should be `class MyNewClass`.

Comment: @ljacqu. When asked, it contained no code. The code was added, but by that time the close votes had gone through.

Comment: The question was "What's wrong with my code?" with *no code in sight*. Unfortunately, I am not clairvoyant, so I voted to close.

Comment: A class can't be public/private. Only methods OF that class can be public/private. so your `public MyNewClass extends MyClass` is exactly as PHP says - a syntax error.

Comment: Have voted to reopen, since it's an answerable question now. (And it has been answered.)

Comment: @HarshalMahajan. You took code that the OP left in a comment and incorporated it into the question body. That's good. Thanks. But your edit comment was "Improved formatting". What? If I'd been reviewing that edit, I'd have rejected it. The one thing it did not do was improve formatting. Please pay better attention to edit comments, especially for suggested edits. "Incorporated information from comments" is a good one for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    public static function funct(){
        echo "JHAN VINCENT VILLASIN";
    }
}
class MyNewClass extends MyClass{};
MyClass::funct();
?>
```